# C++, Adding conditions in class vars

Tags: c++, class, object, conditional-statements

The title may not be right because I can't find an appropriate words for it.
I want to add conditions to some object (instance created by class).

In obj.h: (excluding preprocessor commands)

```
    class obj {
    public:
            void addCondition( bool cond );
            void useCondition();
    private:
            bool conditions;
    };
```

In obj.cpp: (excluding preprocessor commands)

```
    void obj::addCondition( bool cond )
    {
            //What to write here, is the question in short!!!
    }

    void obj::useCondition()
    {
            if(conditions)
            {
              //Do something...
            }
    }
```

Suppose that the conditions was:
        conditions = value1 > value2;
I wanted to 'ADD' a condition in conditions so, that it becomes something like that:

```
    conditions = (value1 > value2) || (value3 <= value4);
```

OR

```
    conditions = (value 1 > value2) && (value3 <= value4);
```

If I am wrong about something in asking things, I am sorry! If you know something other than the answer but the whole different thing that does the same thing, don't hesitate to discuss it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a job for lambdas and `std::function<bool()>` perhaps?

Comment: @cdhowie Can you explain me what are lambdas and std::function<bool()>? Looks like a C++11 thing.

Comment: It is a C++11 thing. You can do the same stuff in C++03 but the syntax is a lot more verbose.

Comment: Whatever it is! Give me a proper explanation on both methods: C++11 lambda and C++03 verbosy syntax.

Comment: I can, but first can you clarify from where the values `value1` through `value4` come from? Are they data members, or global variables, or function parameters, or what? Who supplies them?

Comment: These values are data members of other objects (instances of class obj). Ok, perhaps, I should call them obj0.val = value1 and obj1.val = value2. But how is that important to know? Question is how to add a condition to a condition of a data member of class (like obj)!

Comment: Context is very important, especially in a case like this where its is unclear what you are trying to do.  The question is very vague.  Functional requirements and context will make it clearer what your intent is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you know why `conditions` field and `condition` parameter are both simple boolean variables. If that is true, it could be very simple, but you should replace `addCondition` with `andCondition` and `orCondition` :

```
void obj::andCondition( bool cond )
{
        conditions = conditions && condition;
}
void obj::orCondition( bool cond )
{
        conditions = conditions || condition;
}
```

And you should define whether conditions is initialy true or false. You can always set it to a defined value, because with code above :

```
obj.andCondition(false);
```

sets `conditions` to false, and

```
obj.orCondition(true);
```

sets `conditions` to true

---

Edit per comments:

The above answer is based on the requirement that `conditions` is a simple boolean variable, and `condition` is a simple boolean value.

Here is one example of what could be done if you want to re-evaluate the condition.

A class *and-ing* *(resp. or-ing)* conditions represented by boolean variables evaluated at the moment where `useCondition` is used :

```
class andcond {
    std::list<bool *> conditions;

public:
    void addCondition(bool &condition) {
        conditions.push_back(&condition);
    }
    bool isCondition();
};

bool andcond::isCondition() {
    bool retval = true;
    for (std::list<bool *>::iterator it = conditions.begin(); it != conditions.end(); it++) {
        retval = retval && **it;
    }
    return retval;
}

int main() {
    bool a=false, b=true;
    andcond c;
    c.addCondition(a);
    c.addCondition(b);
    std::cout << c.isCondition() << std::endl;  // is false here

    a = true;
    std::cout << c.isCondition() << std::endl; // is true here

    return 0;
}
```

Note : `conditions` is a list of pointers to boolean variables that can be re-evaluated

You could even be more genereral by defining a full hierarchy of condition classes implementing a `bool eval()` method, for example the equality or inequality between 2 variables, and combinable by `and` and `or`. But it is way too complex for a disgression on an initial answer on SO. But you can try to implement this idea and ask more precise questions here when stuck ...

Comment: Thanks! No lambda, no verbosy syntax! I can't believe it to be that simple. Initial value of data members should always be setted through constructors! But anyway, your answer looks fine.

Comment: @user3820248 Ah, if it was this simple then that's great. I was under the impression that the condition would need to be *re-evaluated* when `useCondition()` was called, which would require functors.

Comment: re-evaluated! I don't get it!

Comment: @cdhowie Whatever he answered, it doesn't matter! I am waiting for your answer as I believe it to be better than that!

Comment: @user3820248 : could you say what the problem is ? And could you give real examples of use ? cdhowie and I did not understand same thing from your question, so you should probably try to be more clear

Comment: @user3820248 I mean, if the values being considered can change between the time you call `addCondition()` and `useCondition()`, and you want `useCondition()` to always use the most recent values of these variables, then you would need functors. If not then Serge's answer is sufficient.

Comment: This can be a case! Values can change between addCondition() and useCondition(). Serge Ballesta, your answer is right and sufficient but I don't accept it as an answer as I wanted to know what 'other' are the ways for doing the same thing!

Comment: Serge Ballesta, fine! Thanks for cooperating with me! I got it! And sorry! Next time, when I ask, I will ask more clearly and precisely. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Please reply to my new question: "C++, Adding conditional statements to class vars" (no link, search it). The answer here, is fine but there is still a problem which is discussed there!