# C++, Adding conditional statements in class vars

Tags: c++, list, sdl, collision-detection, sdl-2

Sorry, but I have to repeat the same question as I asked before "[C++, Adding conditions in class vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805137/c-adding-conditions-in-class-vars/27806038#27806038)".

I am using SDL2 here.

In obj.h: (excluding preprocessor commands)

```
class obj {
public:
        SDL_Rect clip;
        void addCollideWith( SDL_Rect rect );
        void hasCollide();
        void clearCollideWith();
private:
        std::list<bool *> collideWith;
};
```

In obj.cpp: (excluding preprocessor commands)

```
void obj::addCollideWith( SDL_Rect rect )
{
        collideWith.push_back(SDL_HasIntersection(obj.clip, rect));
}

void obj::hasCollide()
{
    bool retval = true;
    for (std::list<bool *>::iterator it = collideWith.begin(); it != collideWith.end(); it++) 
    {
        retval = retval && **it;
    }
    return retval;
}

void clearCollideWith()
{
    collideWith.clear();
}
```

Inside main function, I am saying that the object moves by one pixel and every time when it moves by one pixel, it checks for collision with other objects. I cleared the pointer thing '*' as I am not putting in **variables** as you can see: `collideWith.push_back(SDL_HasIntersection(obj.clip, rect));`. What I do is to make it move a pixel, clear collideWith and add collideWith condition again for **updating** whether it is true or false.

Now, whats the problem?

Its making the program really really slow! If I remove collideWith thing and then, starts the program, it gets a lot more smoother. Now, what I want, is to store the **statement** rather than true or false. `std::list` takes:

```
collideWith.pushBack(true /*OR*/ false);
```

But what I want is:

```
collideWith.pushBack(/*statement determining whether it is true or false*/ var1 > var2);
```

Please do complain if context is missing or the question is somehow, not understandable!
(NOTE: Context related to moving the object and declaring obj clip sub-vars is not mentioned as they are not a part of question.)

Comment: A list of bool *pointers* looks strange to me, but I don't know anything about SDL. Could you try vector instead? It's more efficient than list.

Comment: Why do you want to save the statement, and what is the statement? Do you want to store the reason why there is a collision, the other colliding objects maybe?

Comment: Also why not use `std::find` and search for false instead of iterating the entire list every time? And why not just store 1 bool flag if any false has been received. Do you need to store all of them?

Comment: Also, your logic does not make too much sense, you could cache the value of `hasCollide` and update it only when calling `addCollideWith` and reset it when `clearCollideWith`

Comment: And as very last nit-picking comment: It should probably be called Collision: `addCollision`, `hasCollision` and `resetCollisions` in proper english

Comment: let me answer: 1-Whether this logic makes sense or not, it works very fine and the problem that I want to discuss is that, the booleans that I stored, don't get updated. I have to clear/reset `hasCollide` and then add the updated value to get the required result. I want them not to be updated to get that result. This surely increases performance! 2-Whether its list, vector or find, the same problem persists. I want a solution of this problem, not efficient method that still has that problem. 3-Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to replace

```
    std::list<bool *> collideWith;
```

with

```
    std::list<SDL_Rect> collideWith;
```

in order to track of the rectangles that you want to considere.

The implementation could be :

```
void obj::addCollideWith( SDL_Rect rect )
{
        collideWith.push_back(rect);
}

// to test if it collides with at least one rectangle
bool obj::hasCollide()
{
    bool retval = false;
    for (std::list<SDL_Rect>::iterator it = collideWith.begin(); it != collideWith.end(); it++) 
    {
        retval = retval || SDL_HasIntersection(obj.clip, *it);
    }
    return retval;
}

// to test if it collides with all rectangles
/* bool obj::hasCollide()
{
    bool retval = true;
    for (std::list<SDL_Rect>::iterator it = collideWith.begin(); it != collideWith.end(); it++) 
    {
        retval = retval && SDL_HasIntersection(obj.clip, *it);
    }
    return retval;
} */
```

Comment: Again, thanks for answering and sorry for repeating the same question again. The previous method that you said, works pretty well but it have some downsides as well. I have a question: If I change the properties(x, y, w, h) of the SDL_Rect, will I need not to update these values again?

Comment: @user3820248 If properties of rectangle may change over the time, you should use a container of pointers to the rectangles instead of copies of the rectangles themselves.

Comment: Fine, I will try this and then, upvote this answer if all goes good! Thanks for answering!

Comment: Why not `for(const auto & rect : collideWith)` and `retval |= SDL_HasIntersection(obj.clip, rect);`?

Comment: I found a problem! How can I access SDL_Rect properties from `**it`? If I have to use its properties in `hasCollide`, what should I do?

Comment: @user3820248 : **You** wrote in your question `SDL_HasIntersection(obj.clip, rect)`. If you could use it originaly and if `**it` is an SDL_Rect, you should be able to use `SDL_HasIntersection(obj.clip, **it);`

Comment: @Serge Ballesta : I know and it works. But if I have to reach a property of SDL_Rect through `**it`, how am I supposed to do that? Instead of `SDL_HasIntersection(obj.clip, **it);`, if I want something like `obj.clip.x + obj.clip.w <= /* the SDL_Rect properties of **it: consider that the SDL_Rect, it contains, is itRect */ itRect.x`, how am I suppose to do such a thing? ( Hope that you understand what I mean! )

Comment: I got the solution. `obj.clip.x + obj.clip.w <= rectX(**it)` where rectX takes **SDL_Rect** and returns its **x position** of it. I am really sorry for wasting your precious time!

Comment: @user3820248 I didn't understand what your problem was. You can simply use `(**it).x` or `(*it)->x`, since `*it` is a `SDL_Rect *`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Yeah, thats my problem! Actually, I haven't learned STL yet and I am still learning C++. I don't know that I can access properties of SDL_Rect from iterator by such a simple way.